# excel function to find 1 student in more than 1 course

Tags: excel

I am working on a file that has students and the courses in which they have enrolled. I have to find if they have enrolled in more than 1 course. which formula will be suitable in excel?

Comment: Maybe COUNTIFS but impossible to know without sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using following formula (using the helper column "Both together"):

```
=COUNTIF(C$2:C6, C6)
```

Where my data look as follows:

[image]

The column "Both together" consists of the following formula:

```
=A2 & "|" & B2
```

Comment: Or `=COUNTIFS(A$2:A7,A2,B$2:B7,B2)` without the helper column if OP has newer Excel version.